How can I count frequency of a list faster?
I have a list
list = RandomInteger[{120, 180}, {20}]

I want to count from the list elements $a$ satisfying conditions: $120\leqslant a <130$, $130\leqslant a <140$, $120\leqslant a <130$, $130\leqslant a <140$, $140\leqslant a <150$, $150\leqslant a <160$,$160\leqslant a <170$, $170\leqslant a \leqslant 180$.
I tried
Clear["Global`*"];
list = RandomInteger[{120, 180}, {20}]
h1 = Flatten[SequenceCases[list, {a_} /; 120 <= a < 130], 1]
Length[h1]
h2 = Flatten[SequenceCases[list, {a_} /; 130 <= a < 140], 1]
Length[h2]
h3 = Flatten[SequenceCases[list, {a_} /; 140 <= a < 150], 1]
Length[h3]
h4 = Flatten[SequenceCases[list, {a_} /; 150 <= a < 160], 1]
Length[h4]
h5 = Flatten[SequenceCases[list, {a_} /; 160 <= a < 170], 1]
Length[h5]
h6 = Flatten[SequenceCases[list, {a_} /; 170 <= a <= 180], 1]
Length[h6]


How can I count frequency of a list faster?

BinCounts[list, {120, 180, 10}]

I don't think you'll find anything faster than this!

@xzczd Thank you very much.

@xzczd  BinCounts[list, {120, 180, 10}] doesn't count numbers together as supposed in condition $170\leq a \leq 180$.  If there are numbers $180$ they are not counted in.

@Artes Oh you're right… but wait, OP write 170 <= a < 180 in his code. @minhthien which is the desired condition?

@xzczd I forgot it.

Do you need to include bins with a count of zero?

list = {
        126, 157, 165, 126, 174,
        158, 150, 174, 179, 157,
        152, 177, 162, 120, 125,
        125, 129, 156, 154, 135
       };


A variant using GatherBy and IntegerDigits:
Length /@ GatherBy[Sort@list, Part[IntegerDigits[#], 2] &]


{6, 1, 7, 2, 4}


SortBy[GatherBy[RandomInteger[{120,180},{20}],Floor[#/10]&],Min]

(* {{126,124,125,124},{137},{146,144,145,149},
{154,157,157,157},{164,162,165,168,167},{171,179}} *)

Length /@ %

{4,1,4,4,5,2}

From the question and the sample code, I am not sure how to treat the case of a=180.

I think @xzczd 's suggestion is the fastest but does need a slight adjustment to get the 180 values incorporated.
SeedRandom[12345];
list = RandomInteger[{120, 180}, {100000}];

c = BinCounts[list, {120, 190, 10}];
n = Length[c];
If[c[[n]] == 0, c = c[[1 ;; n - 1]],
  c[[n - 1]] = c[[n - 1]] + c[[n]]; c = c[[1 ;; n - 1]]];
c
(* {16174, 16456, 16283, 16595, 16378, 18114} *)

